# CSP upgrade-insecure-requests not upgrading iframe requests

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, iframe, meta-tags, content-security-policy

I have a iframe which has insecure source http://example.com inside my site (https://example.com) and I have a CSP policy `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to get rid of the Mixed Content error. This works fine as the insecure request gets upgraded as https://example1.com. But the example1.com redirects the request to another domain which is insecure again as http://example2.com and it is blocked by the CSP as a mixed content loading in a secured site. I need to fix this and tried few ways of white listing both the domains to make sure the are not get blocked by using `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="child-src self http://example1.com http://example1.com">`.

And I read about the CSP specifications to know more about to solve the issue but couldn't get any. Have any one faced the same issue and know any solutions?